# C++ Error Primary Expression Before

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>

    using namespace std;

    string name;
    string friend;
    int gender;
    int drive;

    int main()
    {

    //Name prompt for future reference
    cout << "Hello. I want to play a game. You'll be going on a";
    cout << std::endl;
    cout << "wild ride with it's own ups and downs.";
    cout << std::endl;
    cout << "To start out what is your name?";
    cout << std::endl;
    cin >> name;

    //Determining Which Gender the player identifies with
    cout << "Perfect " <<name;
    cout << ". We shall ask a few more questions to determine";
    cout << std::endl;
    cout << "path will be best suited for you.";
    cout << std::endl;
    cout << "What is your gender?";
    cout << std::endl; 
    cout << "If Male enter 1";
    cout << std::endl;
    cout << "If Female enter 2";
    cout << std::endl;
    cin >> gender;
    cout << std::endl;



    //Now we shall start the path determined by the chosen gender
    if(gender == 1) 
    {cout << "Fantastic! You're a male so that means you are very simple.       With that being said let us get started.";}
    else
    {cout << "Hmm... This seems to be a little difficult our systems indicate that putting you into situations seems a little bit more... complex. Never the matter. Let us get started!";} 
    cout << std::endl;

    //Now the actual story begins.
    if(gender == 2) 
    {cout << "You've been invited to a friends party. Although your mother doesn't";
    cout << std::endl;
    cout << "like you driving that far by yourself. What is your friend's name?";
    cout << std::endl;
    cin >> friend;
    cout << std::endl;
    cout << "They offer to drive you, but you can also drive yourself and risk";
    cout << std::endl;
    cout << "getting into trouble with your mother. What option shall you choose";
    cout << std::endl;
    cout << "If you want to drive yourself enter 1";
    cout << std::endl;
    cout << "If you want "<<friend;
    //One of the problems Primary Experession Before <<friend
    cout << " to drive you enter 2";
    cout << std::endl;
    cin >> drive;
    cout << std::endl;}
    if ((gender == 2) && (drive == 1))
    {cout << std::endl;
        cout << "You have chosen to drive yourself. You start up your car and";
        cout << std::endl;
        cout << "realize you don't have the address for your friends house.";
        cout << std::endl;
        cout << "You pull over at a nearby gas station to text " << friend;
        cout << " and ask";
        cout << std::endl;
        cout << "her what the address is. Her reply to you is";
        cout << std::endl;
        cout << "Just come to my house. I'll drive you there.";
        cout << std::endl;
        cout << "You decide to push the issue of driving yourself.";
        cout << std::endl;
        cout <<friend" texts you the address and you put it into your GPS and start driving.";
        cout << std::endl;
        cout << "You make it to the party and beat "<<friend;
        cout << " to the party";
        cout << std::endl;
        cout << "by five minutes. When she gets there she says that she doesn't";
        cout << std::endl;
        cout << "like the fact that you drove yourself.";
    cout << std::endl;} 
     if ((gender == 2) && (drive == 2))
    {cout << std::endl;
cout << "You ride with " <<friend;
cout << " and you have fun and crack";
cout << std::endl;
cout << "some jokes about your parents and boys";
cout << std::endl;
cout << "You two make it there and there are already a few other";
cout << std::endl;
cout << "people there";
cout << std::endl;}
    if ((gender == 2) && (drive <= 2))
    {cout << std::endl;
        cout << "You are at the party and you go inside";
cout << std::endl;
cout << "your friends house with " <<friend;
cout << std::endl;}

return 0;
    }
```

The problem is each time the expression friend; comes up it gives me an error. I've tried modeling it after the name; but it still won't work. I've tried looking the answer up but I can not understand anything of what anyone else is asking or saying as I am a beginner in C++

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *"The problem is each time the expression `friend;` comes up it gives me an error."*

`friend` is a c++ language keyword. You can't use it as variable name.